# CNTK Evaluate model has two inputs C++

Tags: c++, machine-learning, cntk

I have a project based on CNTK 2.3. I used the code from the integration tests to train MNIST classifier like this:

```
    auto device = DeviceDescriptor::GPUDevice(0);

    const size_t inputDim = sizeBlob * sizeBlob;
    const size_t numOutputClasses = numberOfClasses;
    const size_t hiddenLayerDim = 200;

    auto input = InputVariable({ inputDim }, CNTK::DataType::Float, L"features");

    auto scaledInput = ElementTimes(Constant::Scalar(0.00390625f, device), input);
    auto classifierOutput = FullyConnectedDNNLayer(scaledInput, hiddenLayerDim, device, std::bind(Sigmoid, _1, L""));
    auto outputTimesParam = Parameter(NDArrayView::RandomUniform<float>({ numOutputClasses, hiddenLayerDim }, -0.05, 0.05, 1, device));
    auto outputBiasParam = Parameter(NDArrayView::RandomUniform<float>({ numOutputClasses }, -0.05, 0.05, 1, device));
    classifierOutput = Plus(outputBiasParam, Times(outputTimesParam, classifierOutput), L"classifierOutput");

    auto labels = InputVariable({ numOutputClasses }, CNTK::DataType::Float, L"labels");
    auto trainingLoss = CNTK::CrossEntropyWithSoftmax(classifierOutput, labels, L"lossFunction");;
    auto prediction = CNTK::ClassificationError(classifierOutput, labels, L"classificationError");

    // Test save and reload of model

    Variable classifierOutputVar = classifierOutput;
    Variable trainingLossVar = trainingLoss;
    Variable predictionVar = prediction;
    auto combinedNet = Combine({ trainingLoss, prediction, classifierOutput }, L"MNISTClassifier");
    //SaveAndReloadModel<float>(combinedNet, { &input, &labels, &trainingLossVar, &predictionVar, &classifierOutputVar }, device);

    classifierOutput = classifierOutputVar;
    trainingLoss = trainingLossVar;
    prediction = predictionVar;


    const size_t minibatchSize = 64;
    const size_t numSamplesPerSweep = 60000;
    const size_t numSweepsToTrainWith = 2;
    const size_t numMinibatchesToTrain = (numSamplesPerSweep * numSweepsToTrainWith) / minibatchSize;

    auto featureStreamName = L"features";
    auto labelsStreamName = L"labels";
    auto minibatchSource = TextFormatMinibatchSource(trainingSet, { { featureStreamName, inputDim },{ labelsStreamName, numOutputClasses } });

    auto featureStreamInfo = minibatchSource->StreamInfo(featureStreamName);
    auto labelStreamInfo = minibatchSource->StreamInfo(labelsStreamName);

    LearningRateSchedule learningRatePerSample = TrainingParameterPerSampleSchedule<double>(0.003125);
    auto trainer = CreateTrainer(classifierOutput, trainingLoss, prediction, { SGDLearner(classifierOutput->Parameters(), learningRatePerSample) });

    size_t outputFrequencyInMinibatches = 20;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numMinibatchesToTrain; ++i)
    {
        auto minibatchData = minibatchSource->GetNextMinibatch(minibatchSize, device);
        trainer->TrainMinibatch({ { input, minibatchData[featureStreamInfo] },{ labels, minibatchData[labelStreamInfo] } }, device);
        PrintTrainingProgress(trainer, i, outputFrequencyInMinibatches);

        size_t trainingCheckpointFrequency = 100;
        if ((i % trainingCheckpointFrequency) == (trainingCheckpointFrequency - 1))
        {
            const wchar_t* ckpName = L"feedForward.net";
            //trainer->SaveCheckpoint(ckpName);
            //trainer->RestoreFromCheckpoint(ckpName);
        }
    }

    combinedNet->Save(g_dnnFile);
```

That part works fine and I train the model then save to a model file. But when I try to evaluate a simple image to test the model it looks like something is wrong in the model.

```
// Load the model.
    // The model is trained by <CNTK>/Examples/Image/Classification/ResNet/Python/TrainResNet_CIFAR10.py
    // Please see README.md in <CNTK>/Examples/Image/Classification/ResNet about how to train the model.
    FunctionPtr modelFunc = Function::Load(modelFile, device);

    // Get input variable. The model has only one single input.
    std::vector<Variable> inputs = modelFunc->Arguments();
    Variable inputVar = modelFunc->Arguments()[0];

    // The model has only one output.
    // If the model has more than one output, use modelFunc->Outputs to get the list of output variables.
    std::vector<Variable> outputs = modelFunc->Outputs();
    Variable outputVar = outputs[0];

    // Prepare input data.
    // For evaluating an image, you first need to perform some image preprocessing to make sure that the input image has the correct size and layout
    // that match the model inputs.
    // Please note that the model used by this example expects the CHW image layout.
    // inputVar.Shape[0] is image width, inputVar.Shape[1] is image height, and inputVar.Shape[2] is channels.
    // For simplicity and avoiding external dependencies, we skip the preprocessing step here, and just use some artificially created data as input.
    Mat image = imread(".....");
    uint8_t* imagePtr = (uint8_t*)(image).data;
    auto width = image.cols;
    auto heigth = image.rows;


    std::vector<float> inputData(inputVar.Shape().TotalSize());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < inputData.size(); ++i)
    {
        auto curChVal = imagePtr[(i)];
        inputData[i] = curChVal;
    }

    // Create input value and input data map
    ValuePtr inputVal = Value::CreateBatch(inputVar.Shape(), inputData, device);
    std::unordered_map<Variable, ValuePtr> inputDataMap = { { inputVar, inputVal } };

    // Create output data map. Using null as Value to indicate using system allocated memory.
    // Alternatively, create a Value object and add it to the data map.
    std::unordered_map<Variable, ValuePtr> outputDataMap = { { outputVar, nullptr } };

    // Start evaluation on the device
    modelFunc->Evaluate(inputDataMap, outputDataMap, device);

    // Get evaluate result as dense output
    ValuePtr outputVal = outputDataMap[outputVar];
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> outputData;
    outputVal->CopyVariableValueTo(outputVar, outputData);

    PrintOutput<float>(outputVar.Shape().TotalSize(), outputData);
```

I run the same code on c# and it works fine. What I found as a difference is that modelFunc->Arguments() should have one argument but it has two - it finds features and labels as two inputs but I need to have only feature as an input and it throws the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find input and output variables by name, instead of `modelFunc->Arguments()[0]`.

```
Variable inputVar;
GetInputVariableByName(modelFunc, L"features", inputVar);

Variable outputVar;
GetOutputVaraiableByName(modelFunc, L"classifierOutput", outputVar);
```

`GetInputVariableByName` and `GetOutputVaraiableByName()` come from 
https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/v2.3.1/Tests/EndToEndTests/EvalClientTests/CNTKLibraryCPPEvalExamplesTest/EvalMultithreads.cpp#L316

Comment: Thanks, I didn't expect that could be the problem.